# Simple Javascript Math Function

Tags: javascript, math

This should be easy, but for some reason I keep approaching it wrong.

I need to incrementally increase a base number, on a one to infinity scale.

I have a number representing in milliseconds the duration of an animation, starting at 750. I have another number, representing the number of elements we are skipping.

```
var animationDuration = 750;
var difference = Math.abs(currentPanelIndex - target); //somewhere from 1 - X
```

I need to increase animationDuration incrementally for each number in difference.

Comment: What's the incrementation for? What does it mean to "skip elements"? What is the animation doing? What are  `currentPanelIndex` and `target`?

Comment: Base number? Skipped elements? I don't understand what you're asking -- can you show some pseudo-code of what you'd like to happen? How are `animationDuration`, `currentPanelIndex` and `target` related? (That's probably the _core_ of your question, but they're too unobvious for me to understand so far.)

Comment: A bit more detail on your question would be useful, it's not quite clear what you're trying to achieve here.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solution:

Math.abs(currentPanelIndex - target) gives us our difference
(animationDuration / 10) gives us an increment that is 1/10 of the standard duration

So:
var currentDuration = Math.abs(currentPanelIndex - target) * (animationDuration / 10) + animationDuration;

Answer (score 2):

```
  animationDuration = difference * increment ??
```